# How to install PyQt for Python 3 in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: qt, python3, pyqt

I found some tutorials online for earlier versions of Ubuntu but they didn't seem to work on Ubuntu 14.10; either that or I was doing it the wrong way.

I want to use Qt Designer to design a GUI, use PyQt to covert it to .py, then use it in Python.

What packages do I need to install to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All the tools you need are included in Ubuntu repositories. You must install the package `qtcreator`, which has an [integrated](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-to-know.html) QtDesigner, and the package `pyqt5-dev-tools`, which provides `pyuic5`, a utility that generates Python code from `.ui` files.

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator pyqt5-dev-tools
```

Comment: Small note for those that follow.  The module is found by importing like `import PyQt5` .

Answer (score 0):

**Run these in a Terminal:**

> sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
>
> sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
>
> sudo apt-get install qtcreator pyqt5-dev-tools

**Run PyQt5 Designer, located at:**

> /usr/bin/designer

**Run PyQt5 User Interface Compiler (PYUIC5) to convert .ui to .py**

> pyuic5 gui.ui -o gui.py

**Run PyQt5 Resource Compiler (PYRCC5) to convert .qrc to .py**

> pyrcc5 images.qrc -o images_rc.py

Answer (score -1):

1. Install `python3`.
2. Install `sip`.
3. Install `python3-pip`.
4. Run the command: `pip3 install pyqt5`

Comment: is it pip or sip?

Comment: @HafizShehbazAli It may be that `sip-dev` was intended instead of `sip`, but `pip` doesn't make sense here. The Python 3 version of the pip package manager is provided by the `python3-pip` package which is already separately listed. [SIP is related to PyQt.](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro) *mayur*: Can you [edit] this to include an explanation of how to "install **sip**" and why?

Comment: I dont think you can install pyqt5 using pip in case of ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Well, I documented the steps for Installing pyqt5 with qt designer and code generation here: https://gist.github.com/ujjwal96/1dcd57542bdaf3c9d1b0dd526ccd44ff

With this you can generate the code from Qt Designer itself.

### Installation

```
pip3 install --user pyqt5  
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5  
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

---

### Configuring to run from terminal

```
$ qtchooser -run-tool=designer -qt=5
```

**OR**

Write the following in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf`

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

---

### Code Generation

Create `uic.py` file.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import sys

child = subprocess.Popen(['pyuic5' ,'-x',sys.argv[1]],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print(str(child.communicate()[0],encoding='utf-8'))
```

```
$ chmod +x uic.py
```

**Create a symlink:**

```
$ sudo ln uic.py "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/uic"
```

---

### Desktop Entry

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Qt5 Designer
Icon=designer
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer
Type=Application
Categories=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow

Name[en_US]=Qt5 Designer

[Desktop Action NewWindow]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer
```

**save in `~/.local/share/application` with `.desktop` extension**

Comment: where are you putting the uic.py file?

Comment: I don't think we can do `pip3 install --user pyqt5` in ubuntu