# How to install PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm installing ROS from source and get an error about PyQt5.

```
[ 88%] Running SIP generator for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
sip: Deprecation warning: qt_gui_cpp.sip:1: %Module version number should be specified using the 'version' argument
sip: Unable to find file "QtCore/QtCoremod.sip"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zyh/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 80, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/sip', '-c', '/home/zyh/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip', '-b', '/home/zyh/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp/sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/pyqtscripting.sbf', '-I', '/usr/share/sip/PyQt5', '-w', '-x', 'VendorID', '-t', 'WS_X11', '-t', 'Qt_5_9_1', '-x', 'Py_v3', 'qt_gui_cpp.sip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/build.make:89: recipe for target 'sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile' failed
make[2]: *** [sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile] Error 1
```

As we can see, the error comes from `subprocess.CalledProcessError: ...`.
I've found that '/usr/share/sip/PyQt5' doesn't exist.

I've read [How to install PyQt for Python 3 in Ubuntu 14.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612314/how-to-install-pyqt-for-python-3-in-ubuntu-14-10) but it doesn't help. I can `pip install pyqt4` and I can find `PyQt4` in `/usr/share/sip/`.

It seems that ROS is trying to find `PyQt5` in `/usr/share/sip/`, how to install `PyQt5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask the packaging system!

```
apt-cache search pyqt5
```

gives 66 resuts, including

```
...
pyqt5-dev - Development files for PyQt5
pyqt5-dev-tools - Development tools for PyQt5
pyqt5-doc - Documentation for PyQt5
pyqt5-examples - Examples and demos for PyQt5
....
```

Read `man apt` to see how to install these packages, which may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Having altinstall'd Python 3.8.0 alpha 1 the simple approach didn't work.  Also compiling sip & then PyQt5 left errors.

So I gave up for a few days.

To complete my original project I altinstall'd Python 3.7.2 which allowed successful pip install of PyQt5 and its dependencies.

But I wondered, what if I **just copied all the PyQt5 Qt and sip** folders from  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages ? I installed Python 3.8 clean and to my surprise it worked without issues while running a complex gui.

So I suspect that this can be extrapolated to: altinstall the nearest Python distribution with a working PyQt5 and copy all PyQt5 and Qt5 folders to the new one.

Comment: Installed Python 3.8.0 alpha 2 clean this afternoon.  Copied these folders from the Python3.7 site-packages:

PyQt5, PyQt5-5.12.dist-info, PyQt5_sip-4.19.14.dist-info, Qt5.py-0.1.0.dist-info

Works fine with Alpha 2.