# What happened to pyqt5 when upgrading to 20.04.1

Tags: upgrade, python, hplip, pyqt5

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1 my HP Officejet 3830, connected via usb,  stopped working. I downloaded hplip-3.20.9.run from the HP site. When I try to install, all is well until the program tries to get pyqt5. After 3 tries it reports error code 100 and refuses to continue. Is there a way, step by step instructions needed, to install the required dependencies? Or am I going to need a new printer/scanner?

I entered `dpkg -l hplip` and got:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Architecture Description
+++-==============-==============-============-================================>
rc  hplip          3.20.3+dfsg0-2 amd64        HP Linux Printing and Imaging Sy>
```

I entered `driverless` and got:

```
ipp://OfficeJet%203830%20series%20%5BCN94G7Q88806VZ%5D._ipp._tcp.local/
```

Results of `apt policy python3-pyqt5` :

python3-pyqt5:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1
Version table:
5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 500
500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: Hey yeochief2002! "29.04.1" is mentioned in your question title. But in the question, it's mentioned "20.04.1". I guess it's a typo. Please [edit] your question and correct the version number.

Comment: Open terminal and paste: `dpkg -l hplip` and press Enter. Copy the output and [edit] your question and paste the output in the question.

Comment: Are you going to need a new printer/scanner? Highly unlikely, I would say. Say whether the device is USB connected or not. Also, execute `driverless` and give its output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install PyQt5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009840/how-to-install-pyqt5)

Comment: I did the sudo apt install and it seemed to work, no error codes or anything. However, when I ran the hplip the error code came up again

Comment: I misread and failed to notice the device is USB-connected; apologies. The output of `driverless` would still be very useful to know, however. You never know, it could lead to a solution :).

Answer (score 0):

`driverless` provides a URI. It is given above. **Substitute** for it in

```
lpadmin -p PRINT_QUEUE_NAME -v URI -E -m everywhere
```

PRINT_QUEUE_NAME can be anything you choose. Test printing with

```
  lp -d PRINT_QUEUE_NAME /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

This avoids all the nonsense with HPLIP and pyqt5,